# Swift UITextField icon position

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I'm trying to set the position of my custom `UITextField` icon. But when I change the imageView's frame's x and y values, it still places them top left.

Here's the `viewWillAppear` method of my custom `UITextField` class:

```
var imageView = UIImageView();
var image = UIImage(named: "user-icon.png");
imageView.image = image;
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(100, 0, 20, 19);
usernameTextField.leftView = imageView;
usernameTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

Changing the x and y parameters in the `CGRectMake` call does nothing.

Any ideas? I've read that this may be caused by the element's AutoLayout feature. But if I remove that in the StoryBoard then XCode warns me about the app not looking great on multiple devices...

Comment: The image associated with this property should fit the given rectangle. If it does not fit, it is scaled to fit. If you specify a control for your view, the control tracks and sends actions as usual.  **as per apple doc for UITextField** https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/leftView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are setting `UIImageView` to `leftView` of `UITextField`. so it alway comes in left side. if you want `UIImageView` to right side then there is `rightView` option. if you want to add UIImageView to at your specific position then i suggest you to `add as subview` rather then assigning its to `leftView` or `rightView`.

Hope this help you.